# How do you pronounce "new" in British English?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm playing the pronunciation over and over again but I cannot say it myself: Is the word *new* in British English and similar ones pronounced as [nyu], like the word *meow*, or is it pronounced like [ñu:] with the spanish ñ or Czech and Turmen ň?

In other words, is the *n* pronounced with the mouth [positioned](https://www.google.cz/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=878&q=mouth%20n&btnG=Vyhled%C3%A1v%C3%A1n%C3%AD%20pomoc%C3%AD%20obr%C3%A1zku&oq=plato&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2737.3377.0.3657.5.5.0.0.0.0.151.480.2j3.5.0....0...1ac.1.37.img..2.3.209.Xj8ehH6r46A&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch&q=mouth%20n%20pronounciation&imgrc=YU78t90KfI89fM%3A) like in the pronunciation of normal n (like in *nail*) or is it positioned like in the pronunciation of [y](https://www.google.cz/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=878&q=mouth%20ny%20pronounciation&btnG=Vyhled%C3%A1v%C3%A1n%C3%AD%20pomoc%C3%AD%20obr%C3%A1zku&oq=plato&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2737.3377.0.3657.5.5.0.0.0.0.151.480.2j3.5.0....0...1ac.1.37.img..2.3.209.Xj8ehH6r46A&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch&q=mouth%20y%20pronounciation&imgrc=Ed4XoCIQf91asM%3A)?

Comment: Questions of pronunciation are not generally allowed on this site, because there is **so** much variation between different regions and dialects.  You'd have to first specify which region/dialect you want to sound like -- "standard" British, "standard" American, Australian, American South, New York City, London "cockney", Ireland, Scotland, etc. etc.  Believe it or not all of these do pronounce "new" differently.

Comment: @Andrew Pronunciation is on-topic. See the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/new) is good for pronunciation, both for BrE and AmE.

Comment: @Mick Thanks, there's definitive the *ň* variation

Comment: @Mick well heck.  I've seen other questions about pronunciation pulled, so now I don't know what to say.  I guess I just shet mah mouf.

Comment: @Andrew I know. I've been down-voting pronunciation questions too, but only because others have. Of course, asking for general advice and resources about pronunciation is off-topic. And asking "How can I talk posh like wot Mick and Andrew do?" is definitely taboo.

Comment: @Andrew, Mick, no, no, no! Pronunciation is *super* on-topic here. Downvoting questions about pronunciation because accents exist is silly. There are varieties of AmE and BrE pronunciation which are standardly taught to learners. These questions are generally on-topic and answerable.

Comment: @snailplane So why do people do it? This needs to be sorted out on meta.

Comment: This question asks about phonetics, and the phonemic transcriptions in dictionaries alone are insufficient to answer it.  If it is closed with "entirely answerable by a dictionary", I will reopen it.

Comment: @Mick No idea. Ignorance?

Comment: @snailplane That's what I'm going to plead.

Comment: @snailplane if someone is asking here, I always figure the dictionary didn't answer their question.  But some people here can get very "snobbish" about what they think the questioner *ought* to know.  But now I know, so I won't do it again.

Answer (score 3):

In BrE, [*new*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/new) is pronounced with a /y/ sound: "nyew". In AmE, it is "noo".

> **new** [adjective] uk ​ /njuː/ us ​ /nuː/

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: And in Australian it can sound more like "nee" or "neah".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdnYuQ80tKk

Comment: There are many Americans who say *nju* (and *njus* for *news*), myself being one of them. I am actually quite surprised to see *nu* given as the prevalent pronunciation, though this is the case in American dictionaries as well. FWIW, while I also distinguish between *duel* and *dual* (*djuəl* and *duəl*) when most don't, I do say *tʃus* and *sut* for *chews* and *suit*.

Comment: Cambridge is pretty reliable for their British RP recordings. I am never too sure about their AmE versions.

Comment: I think this is not as good as TonyK's answer because, as explained there, there are actually multiple ways this can be realized phonetically. A dictionary gives a phonemic transcription, which doesn't fully answer the question since [nyu] and [ñu:] are phonemically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

To an English-speaking ear, these two variants (consonant sequence `ny` versus palatalised `ñ`) sound identical. In fact, your question is probably incomprehensible to most monolingual English speakers.

For myself (British English), I pronounce it as a palatalised `ñ`. But either variant is fine, and nobody will notice the difference.

Comment: in fact, I'd say ñ is "palatal", not "palatalized"

Answer (score 1):

I want to add my 5 cents to the previous answers as this is the first result on this question from Google.

The right symbol there is `/ɲ/`, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_nasal). That's the sound for Czech/Slovak ň, Polish ń, Spanish  ň, Italian gn, Rusian нь and so on. According to the previous link, the sound is not present in English and you don't find it in a dictionary neither as far as I know.

Therefore, I wouldn't trust answer of English native speaker on this topic as they don't have ň, so they can't really tell difference between n `/n/` and ň `/ɲ/` :-)

According to pronunciation of knew homophone [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knew#English) Americans tends to say `/n(j)uː/`, while Britons `/ɲ(j)uː/`. I think British pronunciation is actually result of relaxed pronunciation – when you try to pronounce `/nju:/` neglectfully, you actually merge n and j and result is `/ɲuː/`.

note: Please, notice that ɲ symbol is actually combination of letter n and j, for an obvious reason.

Comment: The palatal nasal does occur in English. Ca**ny**on. Of course it depends on the dialect and personal rendition. Btw I am curious how this consonant is executed at the end of a word in other languages, say Czech. I can't figure out how to pronounce [kůň](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C5%AF%C5%88) and the audio Wiktionary has for this word is not clear.

Comment: That's `/kænjən/` according to various sources, but original word is cañon from Spanish. So maybe Hispanic Americans say that this way. I think the audio is okay. Can u say ň alone (without any surrounding vowel)? You can say ků and then cut it by pronouncing ň.